# Cannot install Pyside or PyQt4 to use ghost.py

Tags: python, pip, pyqt4, pyside, ghost.py

I am trying to use ghost.py which requires **PySide or PyQt4**. I tried to install PySide with pip.

[PySide Installation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5wpW.png)

Then when I try to install PyQt4 instead, I get this result:

[PyQt4 Installation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lWjC.png)

I checked other questions on stackoverflow and installed PyQt6 instead bu ghost doesn't work with PyQt5-PyQt6. Can anybody help me with these problems. All I want is to be able to use ghost.

Comment: If you're referring to https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py, it says it requires PySide2. Besides, it seems quite old and unmaintained (the latest update is 5 years ago, which is **an awful lot** in terms of web browsers), so I wouldn't suggest using it anyway.

Comment: What can you advise me to use @musicamante ? I just want to develop a simple bot to have a button on a website clicked and then scrape the details in the opened page.

Comment: Look for selenium or use the QtWebEngine framework.